# question about real numbers field and Dedekind cut .

Tags: real-analysis

1.we first defined $\rm{N}$ with two axioms.$0\in\rm{N}$ and for every $x\in\rm{N}$,its successor $x'\in\rm{N}$ as well.
I can not understand the meaning of successor ,our teacher said  it was defined by successor function which could be learned in set theory.But $ZFC$ axioms made me confused.

2.$\rm{Q}$(the set of rational numbers)'definition is more understandable.

3 We defined $\rm{R}$ with Dedekind Cut.We started from a classic example $\sqrt{2}$ and I understood that how the real numbers field was built.I still want to know what the main difference between Dedekind Cut to $\rm{R}$ and $\rm{Q}$.I have proved that if$A$ and $B$ are Dedekind Cut of
$\rm{Q}$ ,the maximum element of $A$ and the minimum element of $B$ cannot exist at the same time. For $\rm{R}$,it seems to be more complicated.

4 How to prove supremum and infimum theory with dedekind cut? Let nonempty $A\subset R$ and lets one of $A$’s upper bound equals to $\beta$. $$\gamma:=\bigcup_{\alpha\in{A}}\alpha\subset{Q}$$
try to prove $\gamma$ is the supremum.This really made me confused .I do not understand how  $\gamma$ was defined .It seems like a union of lots of sets. How could it be a supremum? I need some explaination to help me understand it.Some implication is also welcomed! Buy no direct solution please! I enjoy in solving problem .

Comment: The successor of integer $n$ is simply $n+1$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successor_function

Comment: In the second part, presumably every real number $\alpha$ is identified with a Dedekind cut, which is intuitively $\{q\in\mathbb Q\mid q<\alpha\}$. So you look at real numbers as *sets* of rational numbers. (Note that makes, say, real number $1/2$ a different thing than a rational number $1/2$.) Now, if $A$ is a nonempty set of real numbers - each of them being a subset of rationals: make a union of all of those. That union is again a subset of rationals, but is also a Dedekind cut (prove it!) and so can be considered to be another real number $\gamma$. Then, prove that $\gamma=\sup A$.

Comment: The intuition about $\mathbb N$ is that it is a *succession* with an "initial" element: the number *zero*, and for every element $n$ of the succession the "next one" called the *successor* of $n$. The succession does not end.